# allowDiscUse when using Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

Is there a way to add `allowDiscUse: true` when using jongo to query MongoDB?
I found out that such error - `Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in can be prevented in such a way, that your aggregate looks like

```
aggregate([{$sort:...},{$$skip:...}...],{allowDiscUse: true})
```

but as far as I see `Aggregate` class in Jongo only applies pipeline to itself, which you can then execute with `as` method.

```
MongoCollection catalogCollection = mongoHolder.getCatalogJongo(param.id, false);

Aggregate aggregation = catalogCollection.aggregate("{$match: #}", query.build());
aggregation.and("{$skip: #}", param.offset);
aggregation.and("{$limit: #}", param.limit);
List<BasicDBObject> result = aggregation.as(BasicDBObject.class);
```

Is there any way of passing that parameter to mongo without switching from Jongo to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use options method :

```
AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true).build());

List<BasicDBObject> result = collection.aggregate("...").options(options).as(BasicDBObject.class);
```

See Jongo Aggregate test class to see a working example https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/blob/20ed6e79c0801ae1af2dc3d4fee240e201ad93dd/src/test/java/org/jongo/AggregateTest.java#L120

Comment: hmm, it seems that I use some old version of jongo, I switched to 1.2 and now I can set this, should help I guess! Thanks!

Comment: BTW 1.3.0 has been released last week.